# CocoaPods: spec lint with subspec discards parent spec?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a library called [MeshPipe](https://github.com/nevyn/MeshPipe) which I'm trying to write a PodSpec for. I'm using CocoaPods 0.39.0 on Mac OS X 10.11 with Xcode 7.1.1.

It is a small library with just three files. It also has an optional part which implements support for another library of mine, [Cerfing](https://github.com/nevyn/MeshPipe). In my podspec, I want to include only the core parts in the main pod, and only for people who are actually interested in Cerfing support should get the Cerfing parts and dependency pulled into their project.

To that end, I've written a [podspec](https://gist.github.com/nevyn/cbb6d096083e42b9a8fa) with subspecs: one for the "core" parts:

```
s.subspec "Core" do |core|
  core.source_files  = "MeshPipe/*.{h,m}"
  core.exclude_files = "MeshPipe/main.m"
  core.public_header_files = "MeshPipe/MeshPipe.h"
end
```

and one for the optional 'cerfing' parts:

```
s.subspec "CerfingMeshPipe" do |cerf|
  cerf.source_files  = "CerfingMeshPipeTransport/*.{h,m}"
  cerf.exclude_files = "CerfingMeshPipeTransport/main.m"
  cerf.dependency "Cerfing"
end
```

And then I'm telling CocoaPods that most people will only want the Core part:

```
s.default_subspecs = "Core"
```

This podspec does not lint, because the

```
- NOTE  | [MeshPipe/CerfingMeshPipe] xcodebuild: 
   MeshPipe/CerfingMeshPipeTransport/CerfingMeshPipeTransport.h:10:9:
   fatal error: 'MeshPipe/MeshPipe.h' file not found
```

If I `pod spec lint --no-clean --verbose` and open the resulting project, only the subspec sources are available in the project, and the main MeshPipe files are gone!!

[image: xcode project screenshot]

(Note the absence of MeshPipe/Meshpipe.{h,m} in there!)

If I try to explicitly add a dependency from the subspec to the main spec (`cerf.dependency('MeshPipe/Core')`), CocoaPods tells me that there is a circular dependency from `MeshPipe/Core` to `MeshPipe/Core`.

I've also tried having the sources for core in the top root-level spec, but that yielded the same error.

Please help: Why can't my subspec depend on the parent spec? Surely there's something I'm missing/have misconfigured?

See [Full output of `pod spec lint --verbose`](https://gist.github.com/nevyn/26780ff6af0b467d6f34).

Answer (score 0):

I think I must have accidentally added the dependency on Core on the root spec instead of the subspec. I now get other errors, but no longer get missing header files, nor errors about recursive dependencies. The subspec block now looks like:

```
s.subspec "CerfingMeshPipe" do |cerf|
  cerf.source_files  = "CerfingMeshPipeTransport/*.{h,m}"
  cerf.exclude_files = "CerfingMeshPipeTransport/main.m"
  cerf.dependency "Cerfing"
  cerf.dependency "MeshPipe/Core" # was s.dependency "MeshPipe/core"
end
```